# Php HTML DOM parsing

Tags: php, dom

```
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" id="Table4">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td valign="top" class="tx-strong-dgrey">
        <a class="anc-noul" href="http://www.example.com/catalog/proddetail.asp?logon=&amp;langid=EN&amp;sku_id=0665000FS10129471&amp;catid=25653">
          Apple 8GB 3rd Generation iPod Touch</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td valign="top" class="element-spacer"/>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td valign="top" class="tx-normal-grey">
        Product detail
        <a href="http://www.example.com/catalog/proddetail.asp?logon=&amp;langid=EN&amp;sku_id=0665000FS10129471&amp;catid=25653">
          More Info</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td valign="top" class="element-spacer"/>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td valign="top" class="tx-normal-red">
        <span class="tx-strong-dgrey">Price:</span>
        $189.99</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td valign="top">You save: $9.00 after instant savings</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td valign="top" class="element-spacer"/>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td valign="top" class="tx-normal-grey">
        <a href="http://www.example.com/catalog/subclass.asp?catid=25653&amp;logon=&amp;langid=EN">
          View similar products</a>  
        <a href="http://www.example.com/catalog/mfr.asp?man=Apple&amp;catid=19&amp;logon=&amp;langid=EN">
          View similar products with same brand</a>
      </td></tr>
    <tr>
      <td valign="top" class="element-spacer"/>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to be able to get the $189.99.

```
echo $ret[0]->find('tr', 4)->plaintext;
```

This outputs: 'Price: $189.99'

I just need $189.99, not 'Price:'

Comment: What does `vardump($ret[0]->find('tr', 4))` gives you?

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function vardump() in C:\xampp\htdocs\...

Comment: `var_dump()` is what he meant

Comment: What object/library/function are you using to parse the DOM?  (i.e., what's in $ret[0]?)

Comment: var_dump() outputs some kind of recursive unending txt

{ ["nodetype"]=>  int(1) ["tag"]=>  string(2) "tr" ["attr"]=>  array(0) { } ["children"]=>  array(1) { [0]=>  object(simple_html_dom_node)#2591 (8) { ["nodetype"]=>  int(1) ["tag"]=>  string(2) "td" ["attr"]=>  array(2) { ["valign"]=>  string(3) "top" ["class"]=>  string(14) "tx-normal-grey" } ["children"]=>  array(1) { [0]=>  object(simple_html_dom_node)#2592 (8) { ["nodetype"]=>  int(1) ["tag"]=>  string(4) "span" ["attr"]=>  array(1) { ["class"]=>  string(15) "tx-strong-dgrey" } ["children"]=>  array(0) { } ["nodes"]=>  array(1){....

Comment: $ret =  $html->find('table[id=Table4]');

I'm using Simple HTML DOM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$exp = explode(":", $ret[0]->find('tr', 4)->plaintext);
$price =$exp[1];
```

Comment: That does it. You guys are great.